# MS SQL - Find if someone has worked more than 5 times in a week - looking for overtime

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion-8

I would like to know if I select a static range of dates (May 1 thru June 30 for example) and then tell me if anyone has more than 5 calendar entries in one week (week1, week2, week3, week4). If easier it could be by selecting a week number in place of range of dates and then showing anyone working more than 5 times in week1 for example for the static range of dates.

This will tell me approximately if anyone has overtime scheduled.

**EmpCalendar table** (relevant columns in bold shown) (bullets are sample rows)

**Cal_ID, user_id, days_date, WeekNumber**

- 1, 34, 2015-04-01, Week1
- 3, 34, 2015-04-02, Week1
- 5, 34, 2015-04-03, Week1
- 7, 34, 2015-04-04, Week1
- 8, 34, 2015-04-05, Week1
- 9, 34, 2015-04-06, Week1

So in the above table we see that the Employee with user_id '34' has worked 6 times on WeekNumber of 'Week1'. I need it to return something like:

Tom Thumb (user_id = 34) worked 6 times in Week1 or within dates falling in the same week. Something to that effect. I am using ColdFusion 8 and MS SQL 2008.

Answer (score 0):

`Week1` can be duplicated within different years or months, so correct way of doing this is grouping by `year` and `month` together with `week`:

```
Select UserID, Year(Date), Month(Date), DATEPART( wk, Date), Count(*) As Days
From Table
Where Date Between @StartDate And @EndDate
Group by UserID, Year(Date), Month(Date), DATEPART( wk, Date)
Having Count(*) > 5
```

Comment: Typo, having not havig

Comment: Thanks to all on this one. 'aphrael' had the best match for my needs, Thanks again!

Comment: *RE:  'aphrael' had the best match for my needs* Who or what is 'aphrael' ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple group by (assuming week numbers are not duplicated - depends on how they are assigned in the table):

```
Select UserID, WeekNumber
, count(distinct Days_Date) as DaysWorked
From EmpCalendar
--optional, if you want to limit the dates you're searching
where days_date between @startDate and @endDate    
--not optional
group by UserID, WeekNumber
having count(distinct Days_Date) >= 5
```